# Anaconda don't start and block in loading applications

Tags: python, anaconda, kali-linux

Hi I'm using kali linux
I download and setup Anaconda3 in my machine by following the [Anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) and when I tap in my terminal anaconda-navigator, the anaconda start loading application but nothing happend else.
This screenshot below can explain more what happend

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

if above doesn't work then,
// Solution for Python 3.8, procedure for other version might be a little different.

```
Edit the file: .../anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/vscode.py"

Add "DISTRO_NAME = None" at line 159 in the function _find_linux_install_dir.

154|    def _find_linux_install_dir(self):
155|        INST_DIR = None
156|        exe = os.path.join('/snap', 'bin', 'code')
157|        if os.path.lexists(exe):
158|            INST_DIR = '/snap'
159|        DISTRO_NAME = None   //add this line
160|        for distro in self.distro_map.keys():
161|            _distro_regex = ".*{}/([^ ]*)".format(distro)
162|            m = re.match(_distro_regex, self._conda_api.user_agent)
163|            if m:
164|                DISTRO_NAME = distro
165|                DISTRO_VER = m.group(1)
166|                break
```

Comment: ohh really thanks it's work fine, but why you add the line and you put it None?

Comment: According to Error it was trying to use the variable before even assigning it, so just added created a variable with none value.
if this answer helped you, do accept it as a solution to your problem so that it may help others in the future,